# swagger-codegen install on mac

Tags: scala, restler, swagger

I am trying desperately to get swagger-codegen working on my Macbook Pro with OS X Mountain Lion.

Upgraded Java to 1.7.

```
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

Installed Homebrew.

Uninstalled Mono and Xamarin per "brew doctor".

Installed Xcode command line tools per "brew doctor".

Executed "brew update"

Installed scala "brew install scala".

Installed sbt "brew install sbt"

Executed "sbt"

```
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jecz/Apache/swagger-codegen-master/project
[info] Set current project to swagger-codegen (in build file:/Users/jecz/Apache/swagger-codegen-master/)
```

Executed "./sbt assembly"

```
Detected sbt version 0.13.0
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jecz/Apache/swagger-codegen-master/project
[info] Set current project to swagger-codegen (in build file:/Users/jecz/Apache/swagger-codegen-master/)
[warn] Credentials file /Users/jecz/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
[info] ResourceExtractorTest:
[info] ResourceExtractor
[info] - should get 3 apis from a resource listing
[info] ApiExtractorTest:
[info] ApiExtractor
[info] - should verify the deserialization of the store api
[info] ResourceListingValidationTest:
[info] - should not have base path
[info] - should fail resource listing without apiVersion
[info] - should fail with missing paths in a ResourceListing
[info] ApiListingReferenceValidationTest:
[info] - should deserialize an ApiListingReference
[info] - should serialize an ApiListingReference
[info] ApiDescriptionValidationTest:
[info] - should fail to deserialize an ApiDescription with path, method, return type
[info] OperationValidationTest:
[info] - should fail to deserialize an Operation with missing param type
[info] - should serialize an operation
[info] ResponseMessageValidationTest:
[info] - should deserialize an ResponseMessage
[info] - should serialize an operation
[info] ParameterValidationTest:
[info] - should deserialize another param
[info] - should deserialize a parameter
[info] - should serialize a parameter
[info] ModelValidationTest:
[info] - should deserialize a model
[info] - should serialize a model
[info] ModelRefValidationTest:
[info] - should deserialize a model ref
[info] - should serialize a model ref
[info] ModelPropertyValidationTest:
[info] - should deserialize a model property with allowable values and ref
[info] - should serialize a model property with allowable values and ref
[info] - should deserialize a model property with allowable values
[info] - should serialize a model property with allowable values
[info] - should deserialize a model property
[info] - should serialize a model property
[info] AllowableValuesValidationTest:
[info] - should deserialize allowable value list
[info] - should serialize allowable values list
[info] - should deserialize allowable values range
[info] - should serialize allowable values range
[info] ResourceListingSerializersTest:
[info] - should deserialize an ResourceListing with no apis
[info] - should serialize an ApiListingReference with no apis
[info] - should deserialize an ResourceListing
[info] - should serialize an ApiListingReference
[info] ApiListingReferenceSerializersTest:
[info] - should deserialize an ApiListingReference
[info] - should serialize an ApiListingReference
[info] ApiDescriptionSerializersTest:
[info] - should deserialize an ApiDescription with no ops
[info] - should serialize an ApiDescription with no operations
[info] - should deserialize an ApiDescription
[info] - should serialize an ApiDescription
[info] OperationSerializersTest:
[info] - should deserialize an Operation
[info] - should serialize an operation
[info] ErrorResponseSerializersTest:
[info] - should deserialize an ResponseResponse
[info] - should serialize an operation
[info] ParameterSerializersTest:
[info] - should deserialize another param
[info] - should deserialize a parameter
[info] - should serialize a parameter
[info] ModelSerializationTest:
[info] - should deserialize a model
[info] - should serialize a model
[info] ModelRefSerializationTest:
[info] - should deserialize a model ref
[info] - should serialize a model ref
[info] ModelPropertySerializationTest:
[info] - should deserialize a model property with allowable values and ref
[info] - should serialize a model property with allowable values and ref
[info] - should deserialize a model property with allowable values
[info] - should serialize a model property with allowable values
[info] - should deserialize a model property
[info] - should serialize a model property
[info] AllowableValuesSerializersTest:
[info] - should deserialize allowable value list
[info] - should serialize allowable values list
[info] - should deserialize allowable values range
[info] - should serialize allowable values range
[info] ResourceListingValidationTest:
[info] - should fail resource listing without base path
[info] - should fail resource listing without apiVersion
[info] - should fail with missing paths in a ResourceListing
[info] ApiListingReferenceValidationTest:
[info] - should deserialize an ApiListingReference
[info] - should serialize an ApiListingReference
[info] ApiDescriptionValidationTest:
[info] - should fail to deserialize an ApiDescription with path, method, return type
[info] OperationValidationTest:
[info] - should fail to deserialize an Operation with missing param type
[info] - should serialize an operation
[info] ResponseMessageValidationTest:
[info] - should deserialize an ResponseMessage
[info] - should serialize an operation
[info] ParameterValidationTest:
[info] - should deserialize another param
[info] - should deserialize a parameter
[info] - should serialize a parameter
[info] ModelValidationTest:
[info] - should deserialize a model
[info] - should serialize a model
[info] ModelRefValidationTest:
[info] - should deserialize a model ref
[info] - should serialize a model ref
[info] ModelPropertyValidationTest:
[info] - should deserialize a model property with allowable values and ref
[info] - should serialize a model property with allowable values and ref
[info] - should deserialize a model property with allowable values
[info] - should serialize a model property with allowable values
[info] - should deserialize a model property
[info] - should serialize a model property
[info] AllowableValuesValidationTest:
[info] - should deserialize allowable value list
[info] - should serialize allowable values list
[info] - should deserialize allowable values range
[info] - should serialize allowable values range
[info] SwaggerModelTest:
[info] Swagger Model
[info] - should deserialize ResourceListing
[info] - should deserialize ApiListing
[info] - should deserialize ApiListing with AllowableValues
[info] - should maintain model property order when deserializing
[info] - should deserialize models
[info] ResourceExtractorTest:
[info] ResourceExtractor
[info] - should get 3 apis from a resource listing
[info] ApiExtractorTest:
[info] ApiExtractor
[info] - should verify the deserialization of the store api
09:49:13,840 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
09:49:13,840 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
09:49:13,840 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/Users/jecz/Apache/swagger-codegen-master/target/scala-2.9.1/classes/logback.xml]
09:49:13,991 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
09:49:14,000 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
09:49:14,012 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
09:49:14,114 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - This appender no longer admits a layout as a sub-component, set an encoder instead.
09:49:14,114 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - To ensure compatibility, wrapping your layout in LayoutWrappingEncoder.
09:49:14,114 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - See also http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#layoutInsteadOfEncoder for details
09:49:14,116 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.wordnik] to DEBUG
09:49:14,116 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to ERROR
09:49:14,116 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
09:49:14,117 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
09:49:14,119 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@7b1b9e3a - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

[info] BasicScalaGeneratorTest:
[info] BasicScalaGenerator
[info] - should process a response declaration
[info] - should process a string response
[info] - should process a string array
[info] - should process an unmapped response type
[info] - should get the invoker package
[info] - should get the api package
[info] - should get the model package
[info] - should convert to a declared type
[info] - should convert a string a declaration
[info] - should honor the import mapping
[info] - should quote a reserved var name
[info] - should create a declaration with a List of strings
[info] - should create a declaration with a List of ints
[info] - should create a declaration with a List of floats
[info] - should create a declaration with a List of doubles
[info] - should create a declaration with a List of complex objects
[info] - should verify an api map with query params
[info] - should verify an api map with query params with default values
[info] - should create an api file
[info] BasicGeneratorTest:
[info] BasicGenerator
[info] - should get operations
[info] - should verify ops are grouped by path correctly
[info] - should create a model map
[info] - should create a model file
[info] BasicJavaGeneratorTest:
[info] BasicJavaGenerator
[info] - should process a response declaration
[info] - should process a string response
[info] - should process a string array
[info] - should process an upper-case string array
[info] - should process an unmapped response type
[info] - should get the invoker package
[info] - should get the api package
[info] - should get the model package
[info] - should convert to a declared type
[info] - should convert a string a declaration
[info] - should honor the import mapping
[info] - should quote a reserved var name
[info] - should create a declaration with a List of strings
[info] - should create a declaration with a List of ints
[info] - should create a declaration with a List of floats
[info] - should create a declaration with a List of doubles
[info] - should create a declaration with a List of complex objects
[info] CodegenConfigTest:
[info] PathUtil
[info] - should convert an api name
[info] - should convert a path
[info] CodegenConfig
[info] - should process a response declaration
[info] - should process an unchanged response
[info] - should process an mapped response type
[info] - should get the invoker package
[info] - should get the api package
[info] - should get the model package
[info] - should convert to a declared type
[info] - should honor the import mapping
[info] - should quote a reserved var name
[info] CoreUtilsTest:
[info] CoreUtils
[info] - should verify models are extracted
[info] - should verify operation names
[info] - should find required models
[info] - should find required models from a nested list
[info] PathUtilTest:
[info] PathUtil
[info] - should convert an api name
[info] - should convert a path
[info] - should get determine the basePath implicitly
[info] ResourceListingSerializersTest:
[info] - should deserialize an ResourceListing with no apis
[info] - should serialize an ApiListingReference with no apis
[info] - should deserialize an ResourceListing
[info] - should serialize an ApiListingReference
[info] ApiListingReferenceSerializersTest:
[info] - should deserialize an ApiListingReference
[info] - should serialize an ApiListingReference
[info] ApiDescriptionSerializersTest:
[info] - should deserialize an ApiDescription with no ops
[info] - should serialize an ApiDescription with no operations
[info] - should deserialize an ApiDescription
[info] - should serialize an ApiDescription
[info] OperationSerializersTest:
[info] - should deserialize an Operation
[info] - should deserialize an Operation with an array property
[info] - should serialize an operation
[info] - should deserialize an Operation with array
[info] ErrorResponseSerializersTest:
[info] - should deserialize an Response
[info] - should serialize an operation
[info] ParameterSerializersTest:
[info] - should deserialize another param
[info] - should deserialize a parameter
[info] - should serialize a parameter
[info] ModelSerializationTest:
[info] - should deserialize a model
[info] - should deserialize a model with a set
[info] - should serialize a model
[info] ModelRefSerializationTest:
[info] - should deserialize a model ref
[info] - should serialize a model ref
[info] ModelPropertySerializationTest:
[info] - should deserialize a model property with allowable values and ref
[info] - should serialize a model property with allowable values and ref
[info] - should deserialize a model property with allowable values
[info] - should serialize a model property with allowable values
[info] - should deserialize a model property
[info] - should serialize a model property
[info] - should extract model properties
[info] - should extract model properties with arrays
[info] AllowableValuesSerializersTest:
[info] - should deserialize allowable value list
[info] - should serialize allowable values list
[info] - should deserialize allowable values range
[info] - should serialize allowable values range
[info] CoreUtilsTest:
[info] CoreUtils
[info] - should verify models are extracted
[info] - should verify operation names
[info] - should find required models
[info] - should find required models from a nested list
[info] BasicCSharpGeneratorTest:
[info] BasicCSharpGenerator
[info] - should perserve the name date
[info] - should process a string array
[info] Passed: Total 194, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 194
[info] Including from cache: json4s-ast_2.9.1-3.2.5.jar
[info] Including from cache: jackson-annotations-2.2.2.jar
[info] Including from cache: jackson-core-2.2.2.jar
[info] Including from cache: json4s-core_2.9.1-3.2.5.jar
[info] Including from cache: jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar
[info] Including from cache: paranamer-2.5.6.jar
[info] Including from cache: commons-io-2.3.jar
[info] Including from cache: scala-inflector_2.9.1-1.3.5.jar
[info] Including from cache: json4s-jackson_2.9.1-3.2.5.jar
[info] Including from cache: mockito-all-1.9.0.jar
[info] Including from cache: scallop_2.9.1-0.9.4.jar
[info] Including from cache: scalate-core_2.9-1.6.1.jar
[info] Including from cache: scalate-util_2.9-1.6.1.jar
[info] Including from cache: scala-compiler-2.9.1.jar
[info] Including from cache: scala-library-2.9.1.jar
[info] Including from cache: scalap-2.9.1.jar
[info] Including from cache: slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
[warn] Merging 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Strategy 'discard' was applied to a file
[info] Checking every *.class/*.jar file's SHA-1.
[info] Assembly up to date: /Users/jecz/Apache/swagger-codegen-master/target/scala-2.9.1/swagger-codegen.jar
[success] Total time: 26 s, completed Nov 1, 2013 9:49:34 AM
```

Executed "./bin/scala-petstore.sh"

```
 Please set scalaVersion := "2.10.3" in build.sbt and run ./sbt assembly
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. The problem is:

I installed scala 2.10.2, sbt builds it in a folder called scala-2.10 and this is handled by this line in php-petstore.sh file:

```
if [ -f $APP_DIR/target/scala-$SCALA_RUNNER_VERSION/swagger-codegen.jar ]; then
```

using the bin/Version.scale it maps version numbers with patches to version number with just major and minor versions. Since 2.10.3 is not mapped to 2.10 the error occurres.

```
val version = scala.util.Properties.scalaPropOrElse("version.number", "unknown").toString match {
  case "2.10.0" => "2.10"
  case e: String => e
}
println(version)
```

The solution:
Change 2.10.0 to 2.10.3 (or what ever version you are running)

Comment: +1. Ridiculous, that files now contains cases for `2.10.0`, `2.10.2`, `2.10.3`, and `2.10.4`. I'm using `2.11.5`, and had to add a case for matching `2.11.5 => 2.11`

Answer (score 0):

if you do brew install scala things should start to work

Comment: Updated original question with results.  Seems to be a little closer.  Got the following error: "Please set scalaVersion := "2.10.3" in build.sbt and run ./sbt assembly"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are forgetting "./sbt assembly" after changing a version in build.sbt.

I was also getting:

```
object BeanProperty is not a member of package reflect
[error] import scala.reflect.BeanProperty
```

and tried to [downgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula) to version 2.10.4

It worked after that.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Swagger-Codegen no longer has a dependency on Scala. You can find the installation instruction [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#prerequisites)